# Why does MITIE get stuck on segment classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm building a model using `MITIE` with a training dataset of 1,400 sentences, between 3-10 words long, paired to around 120 intents. My model training get stuck at `Part II: train segment classifier`. I've let it run for 14 hours before terminating.

My machines has `2.4 GHz Intel Core i7` and `8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3` and the `segment classifier` uses all available memory (around 7gb), eventually relying on compressed memory, and at the end of the last session activity monitor showed `32gb` used and `27gb` compressed. And `segment classifier` has never completed.

My current output is below:

```
INFO:rasa_nlu.model:Starting to train component nlp_mitie
INFO:rasa_nlu.model:Finished training component.
INFO:rasa_nlu.model:Starting to train component tokenizer_mitie
INFO:rasa_nlu.model:Finished training component.
INFO:rasa_nlu.model:Starting to train component ner_mitie
Training to recognize 20 labels: 'pet', 'room_number', 'broken_things', '@sys.ignore', 'climate', 'facility', 'gym', 'medicine', 'item', 'exercise_equipment
', 'service', 'number', 'electronic_device', 'charger', 'toiletries', 'time', 'date', 'facility_hours', 'cost_inquiry', 'tv channel'
Part I: train segmenter
words in dictionary: 200000
num features: 271

now do training
C:           20
epsilon:     0.01
num threads: 1
cache size:  5
max iterations: 2000
loss per missed segment:  3
C: 20   loss: 3         0.669591
C: 35   loss: 3         0.690058
C: 20   loss: 4.5       0.701754
C: 5   loss: 3  0.616959
C: 20   loss: 1.5       0.634503
C: 28.3003   loss: 5.74942      0.71345
C: 25.9529   loss: 5.72171      0.707602
C: 27.7407   loss: 5.97907      0.707602
C: 30.2561   loss: 5.61669      0.701754
C: 27.747   loss: 5.66612       0.710526
C: 28.9754   loss: 5.82319      0.707602
best C: 28.3003
best loss: 5.74942
num feats in chunker model: 4095
train: precision, recall, f1-score: 0.805851 0.885965 0.844011
Part I: elapsed time: 180 seconds.

Part II: train segment classifier
now do training
num training samples: 415
```

I understand this could be an issue caused by redundant labels (as explained [here](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE/issues/11)); however, all of my labels are unique. My understanding is that training shouldn't take this long or use this much memory. I've seen others posting similar issues with no solution provided yet. What is causing this high memory usage and insane training time? How is it fixed?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue from past several days. Maybe you are running out of RAM. I also have the same 8gb RAM with core i5 3470s a quad core cpu with 4 threads. Training takes a hell lot of time. Increasing the RAM and switching to a faster processor would definitely solve this issue.

Comment: if you are able to solve your problem, tell me also.

Comment: I am using RASA using MITIE as a backend but its taking too much time.